# Is there an alternative to salvagewallet that keeps account info?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core-accounts

I am using the accounts feature of bitcoind , if a wallet gets corrupted and bitcoind is started with -salvagewallet then the account information is lost.

So, is there any built in feature that will rebuilt also my accounts ?

Comment: have you tried to use pywallet to restore the file?

Comment: Haven't tried but I have read this : https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pywallet , and there is no mention about accounts support for this utility.

Comment: well there's a lot more to it than just that one liner. there's an entire thread on it (https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=34028.0). you can do wallet surgery and remove offending errors and then set the rest back in place. if you are a skilled enough wallet surgeon you can leave everything in place. Honestly though: I'm not a huge fan of the accounting feature it causes too many headaches when we should be using other means rather than accounting  (personal opinion though nothing more) :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution once released:

"Add -zapwallettx function, a diagnostic tool to assist in wallet repair" - https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/3659

Comment: Will surely take a look when it is released. Thanks for the heads up.